# IOS Time zone abbreviation without GMT offset. Need directly like IST,EST etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

```
 NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
 NSString *timeZoneAbberivation = [timezone abbreviation];
```

timeZoneAbberivation is printing like GMT+5:30 like that. But I need GMT+5:30 to be printed as IST. (IST is of India/Kolkatta).

Suppose if it is America/Newyork time zone, I need it as EST, etc.

Comment: Did you try putting together a lookup ? should be pretty standard !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `NSDateFormatter`. Look into the `z` format argument which supplies the "short specific non-location format"

[NSDateFormatter Date Formatting Table](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use this:

```
let  zone = TimeZone.current.identifier
print(zone)
```

In Objective-C you can use this:

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];

NSString* timeZoneName = [timeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard 
                                          locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"Name : %@", timeZoneName);
```

Comment: Isn't that what you get from `timeZone.name`?